# skipping digit/word combinations in dictionary using list

Tags: regex, python-3.x, list, dictionary, text

I have a list `e`

```
e = ['s', 'mm', 'ng']
```

and a dict `d`

```
d = {'A1': ['Tomas', 
            'john',
 '2s',
 'Douglas',
    '20ng'],      
 'B1': ['Tomm',        
 '3mm',
 'Sterling',
       'hey']}
```

My goal is to only skip names in `d` that end with a digit and an element from `e`.

For example, `2s` from `d` would be skipped because it has a digit `2` and an element `s` from list `e`.

I have tried the following

```
r = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    r[k] = [s for s in v if not any(s.endswith(val) for val in e)]
```

And I get

```
{'A1': ['john'], 'B1': ['hey']}
```

The code I have is removing elements that end with an `s` e.g. `'Tomas'`

My desired output is the following which has only digits + elements from `e` removed e.g `3mm`

```
{'A1': ['Tomas', 'john', 'Douglas'], 'B1': ['Tomm', 'Sterling', 'hey']}
```

How do I change my code to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this might be close to what you have in mind,

```
import re
e = ['s', 'mm', 'ng']

d = {'A1': ['Tomas',
            'john',
            '2s',
            'Douglas',
            '20ng'],
     'B1': ['Tomm',
            '3mm',
            'Sterling',
            'hey']}
r = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    r[k] = [s for s in v if not any(re.match(r'^[0-9]', s) for val in e)]

print(r)
```

#### Output

> {'A1': ['Tomas', 'john', 'Douglas'], 'B1': ['Tomm', 'Sterling',
>   'hey']}

Here, we'd assume that those that'd start with a digit are undesired, and find those using,

```
re.match(r'^[0-9]', s)
```

and incorporate that in the `if not` statement that you already had in your list comprehension.

Comment: This will remove strings such as `4cm` but `cm` is not an ending in `e`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only exclude those values that end with a digit and value from `e`, you can build a regex on the fly which implements that e.g.

```
\ds$
```

or

```
\dng$
```

We can build that using string concatenation with `val` and then use it in a call to `re.search` to determine if the value matches:

```
import re

e = ['s', 'mm', 'ng']
d = {'A1': ['Tomas', 
            'john',
 '2s',
 'Douglas',
    '20ng'],      
 'B1': ['Tomm',        
 '3mm',
 'Sterling',
       'hey']}
r = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    r[k] = [s for s in v if not any(re.search('\d' + val + '$', s) for val in e)]  
print (r)
```

Output:

```
{'A1': ['Tomas', 'john', 'Douglas'], 'B1': ['Tomm', 'Sterling', 'hey']}
```